# Getting the css attribute value on the site using Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, perl

Good afternoon!

To check the font size of a CSS element on getbootstrap.com in the Firefox browser via Selenium, I use the following script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use Selenium::Firefox;
my $url = 'http://getbootstrap.com';
my $driver = Selenium::Firefox->new();
$driver->get($url);
my $elt = $driver->find_element(
 'h1.mb-3.fw-semibold', 'css');
is $elt->get_css_attribute('font-size'), '72px',
 'Masthead font size is unchanged';
$driver->quit();
done_testing;
```

When the script runs, the test fails:

```bash
❯ ./selenium_properties_css_attribute.pl 
not ok 1 - Masthead font size is unchanged
#   Failed test 'Masthead font size is unchanged'
#   at ./selenium_properties_css_attribute.pl line 12.
#          got: '64px'
#     expected: '72px'
1..1
Killing Driver PID 4132 listening on port 45685...
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
```

Can you please tell me why the test is failing? On the getbootstrap.com page in the Firefox browser, in the Computed tab for the element h1.mb-3.fw-semibold we see that the font size is 72px, but when we run the test we get 64px. Why?

The screenshot showing the font size is 72px:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS for the heading includes:

```css
.bd-masthead h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.525rem + 3.3vw);
}
```

The font size is thus dependent on the width of the viewport. You are not explicitly controlling the width of the Firefox browser viewport.

Comment: If I add a method to the script that opens the browser to full screen, nothing changes, I still get 64px instead of 72px.

Comment: I added a sleep function to the script, opened the developer's console in the browser while the script was running, and saw that the font size, when the screen was running, was 64px, even though the browser was open full screen.

I did the same thing by just opening the browser full screen, without running the script, in which case the font size is already 72px.